# Why I am getting following logs while running my spark code via spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

**I am running the script via this command**

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.2.0 direct_kafka_wordcount.py localhost 9092
```

I am unable to connect my Kafka topic and retrieve information. I have tried everything but no luck. I am running this simple code of wordcount of my live Kafka stream.

> Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/sagar/.ivy2/cache
>       The jars for the packages stored in: /home/sagar/.ivy2/jars
>       :: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/local/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
>       org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11 added as a dependency
>       :: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-be411cc2-fb3f-4049-b222-e3eca55e020b;1.0
>         confs: [default]
>         found org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.2.0 in central
>         found org.apache.kafka#kafka_2.11;0.10.0.1 in central
>         found com.101tec#zkclient;0.8 in central
>         found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.16 in central
>         found org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.7.16 in central
>         found log4j#log4j;1.2.17 in central
>         found com.yammer.metrics#metrics-core;2.2.0 in central
>         found org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.4 in central
>         found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;0.10.0.1 in central
>         found net.jpountz.lz4#lz4;1.3.0 in central
>         found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.2.6 in central
>         found org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 in central
>       :: resolution report :: resolve 1491ms :: artifacts dl 9ms
>         :: modules in use:
>         com.101tec#zkclient;0.8 from central in [default]
>         com.yammer.metrics#metrics-core;2.2.0 from central in [default]
>         log4j#log4j;1.2.17 from central in [default]
>         net.jpountz.lz4#lz4;1.3.0 from central in [default]
>         org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;0.10.0.1 from central in [default]
>         org.apache.kafka#kafka_2.11;0.10.0.1 from central in [default]
>         org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.2.0 from central in [default]
>         org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.4 from central in [default]
>         org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.16 from central in [default]
>         org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.7.16 from central in [default]
>         org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 from central in [default]
>         org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.2.6 from central in [default]
>         ---------------------------------------------------------------------
>         |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
>         |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
>         ---------------------------------------------------------------------
>         |      default     |   12  |   1   |   1   |   0   ||   12  |   0   |
>         ---------------------------------------------------------------------
>       :: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-be411cc2-fb3f-4049-b222-e3eca55e020b
>         confs: [default]
>         0 artifacts copied, 12 already retrieved (0kB/8ms)
>       19/07/09 14:28:08 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/local/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/python/streaming/direct_kafka_wordcount.py",
>   line 48, in 
>           kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
>         File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py",
>   line 146, in createDirectStream
>         File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1257, in **call**
>         File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 328, in get_return_value
>       py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler.
>       : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Broker not in the correct format of : [localhost]
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$SimpleConsumerConfig$$anonfun$7.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:390)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$SimpleConsumerConfig$$anonfun$7.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:387)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$SimpleConsumerConfig.(KafkaCluster.scala:387)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$SimpleConsumerConfig$.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:422)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.config(KafkaCluster.scala:53)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitionMetadata(KafkaCluster.scala:130)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitions(KafkaCluster.scala:119)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:720)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler(KafkaUtils.scala:688)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>         at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>         at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>         at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>         at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: looks like there should be more logs about the exception type

Comment: `caused by ...`  ?

Comment: I have updated my logs please have a look again.

Answer (score 1):

Bad syntax, try this (*check the kafka broker host part*):

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.2.0 
direct_kafka_wordcount.py localhost:9092
```

In general terms, connecting to kafka's bootstrap servers always requires a `host:port` syntax.

Comment: Hey it works finally the task has started but getting another error please have a look
--->
"Caused by: py4j.Py4JNetworkException: Error while sending a command: null response: c
p4
call
L1562686648000
lo707
e

 at py4j.CallbackConnection.sendCommand(CallbackConnection.java:158)
 at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:384)
 ... 24 more"

Comment: pretty self explanatory.  you are sending null to kafka.  check you code in wordcount.py